What is the definition of $\nabla(wf) \in (L^2(\Omega))^d \}.$
Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be a domain and let $w \in L^1(\Omega)$. Define
$$
H_w(\Omega) = \left\{ f \in L^2(\Omega) : \nabla(wf) \in (L^2(\Omega))^d \right\}.
$$

Give reasonable conditions on $w$ so that $H_w(\Omega) = H^1(\Omega)$.

Prove that $H_w(\Omega)$ is a Hilbert space. What is the inner product?

Can you define the trace of $f$ on $\partial\Omega$? [Hint: first consider the trace of $wf$.

Characterize $H_w(\mathbb{R})$ if $w(x)$ is the Heaviside function.

Suppose that $\Omega$ is bounded. Prove that there is a constant $C > 0$ such that for all $f \in H_w(\Omega)$ satisfying $\int_{\Omega} w(x) f (x) \, dx = 0$,
$$
\|f\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \leq C \left( \|\nabla(wf)\|_{L^2(\Omega)} + \|(1 - w)f\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \right).
$$


I wrote the complete question here just for making the context clear. I solved all the 18 questions before this one. However, I do not think I understand the notation $(L^2)^d$, can some one just explain it for me! or mention a reference I can read. Thanks in advance.

It is the space of vector-valued functions $\Omega \to \mathbb R^d$, each component of which is in $L^2(\Omega)$.

If f is a vector valued function then the first condition should be $f \in (L^2)^d$!

@Mr.Proof $f$ is scalar-valued, but $\nabla(wf)$ is vector-valued.

So why there is no such notation in the $H^1={ f \in L^2(\Omega), \nabla f \in L^2(\Omega)}$ space?

@Mr.Proof Strictly speaking, there should be. This is a common (and usually harmless, I'd argue) abuse of notation.

Can you elaborate! this is not helpful.
